# Computing $H_2$ of the closed ball

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I take a 3-simplex to be a triangulation of the ball, with vertices labeled as $w, x, y,$ and $z$. The generic 3-chain in $C_3$ is of the form $\alpha (wxyz)$, where $\alpha \in \Bbb{Z}$. Then, $$\partial(\alpha (wxyz)) = \alpha((xyz) - (wyz) + (wxz) - (wxy)).$$ Thus, im $\partial_3 \cong \Bbb{Z}$ because it is generated by the single 2-chain $(xyz) - (wyz) + (wxz) - (wxy)$. $\partial_2$ will map the general 2-chain $\alpha(xyz) + \beta(wyz)+\gamma(wxz)+\delta(wxy)$ to $$(\alpha + \beta)(yz) + (\gamma - \alpha)(xz) + (\alpha + \delta)(xy) + (\gamma - \beta)(wz) + (\beta-\delta)(wy) + (\gamma + \delta)(wx)$$Set each of the coefficients equal to $0$ and row reduce the matrix (columns correspond to $\alpha, \beta, \gamma,$ and $\delta,$ respectively:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 &1&0&0\\-1&0&1&0\\1&0&0&1\\0&-1&1&0\\0&1&0&-1\\0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&-1\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$There is only one free variable, implying that ker $\partial_2\cong\Bbb{Z}$. Finally, $H_2 =$ ker $\partial_2 /$im $\partial_3$ $\cong \Bbb{Z}/\Bbb{Z} \cong 0.$

Is my process correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to know that $\ker\partial_2\cong\Bbb Z$ and $\text{im}\,\partial_3\cong \Bbb Z$ won't show the quotient is $0$. What if the image is embedded as $5$ times the generator of the original $\Bbb Z$?

In your case, $\ker\partial_2$ is generated by the vector $(1,0,-1,1)$ and $\text{im}\,\partial_3$ is generated by the vector $(1,-1,1,-1)$, so we don't even have containment. Therefore, something is wrong! I suggest that the matrix for $\partial_2$ should be 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&1\\-1&0&1&0\\1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&1&0&-1\\0&-1&-1&0\end{bmatrix};$$
then, amazingly, we get the fact that $\text{im}\,\partial_3 = \ker\partial_2$, and so the quotient is indeed $0$.

Comment: Is your last row correct? It doesn't match up with a reordering of my rows.

Comment: Yours was wrong — gave an impossible situation.

Comment: Where did I go wrong with the $wz$ term?

Comment: You have various signs wrong *and* you didn't reduce correctly to reduced echelon form. You better check your work very carefully.  For example $\partial(wxy) = (xy) - (wy) + (wx)$, which accounts for my last column.  (I used $(xy), (xz), (yz), (wx), (wy), (wz)$ as my ordered basis for $C_2$.)

Comment: I redid my calculations and got $(-1,1,-1,1)$ for the generator of ker $\partial_2$. It's just a scalar multiple of the generator for im $\partial_3$, so now I can conclude they are the same group, right?

Comment: You mean $\pm 1$ times ... So yes. Since $\text{\im}\,\partial_3$ is a subgroup of $\ker\partial_2$, only the generator of  $\text{\im}\,\partial_3$ can be a non-unit multiple ...